# Create a component that represent two table with OneToMany relation in one table

Tags: reactjs

hi  I am a beginar at ReactJs
I have an API that give me a result similar to this :

```
{"id":1,
"command":"gdf",
"product":[{ "id":1,
             "name":"jhg"
             "price":200},
           { "id":2,
             "name":"jhdg"
             "price":300}
          ....
          ],
"total-price":***,
"date-commande:"******"

}
```

and I want to represent it In a React  component table similar to this image :
[image]

I did a lot of research for table but I didn't find what I want
so if someone can help me with the code to do this table in React or any kind of help I would be thankful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can nest table into table like this.

```
renderParentTable() {
  return (
    <table>
      <th>
        //....
      </th>
      {parentData.map((data) => renderRow())}
    </table>
  )
}

renderRow(data) {
  return (
    <>
      <td>data.id</td>
      <td>data.commnad</td>
      {renderProductTable(data.product)}
    </>
  )
}

renderProductTable(productData) {
  return (
    ////....
    {productData.map((data) => renderProductRow())}
  )
}
```